# limit point and basis of a set

Tags: general-topology

Let $Z = \mathbb{R}\cup\{z\}$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to answer two questions:

1. Does every sequence in $Z$ have a limit point?
2. Is $\mathcal{B} = \{U\subseteq \mathbb{R}: U$ open $\}\cup\{(-\infty, a)\cup(b, \infty)\cup\{z\} : a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ a basis for the topology of $Z$?

What I've tried:,

I have taken a constant sequence $\{X,X,\ldots\}$ and tried to show that $X$ is the limit point by using the argument that because this is a constant sequence, it will converge to a single fixed point but I am stuck on how to prove it by using the definition of limit point.

Your help will be appreciated.

Sorry I made a mistake in part 1 I want to ask that set {1,2,3,........} has no limit point. 
Is this sequence has limit point in Z.

Comment: Hello! The reason your question is receiving downvotes is because it is very hard to understand what you are asking. My understanding of what you have written is the following. You let $Z = \mathbb{R}\cup\{z\}$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$. The questions are then (1) Does every sequence in $Z$ have a limit point? and (2) Is $\{U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ open $\}\cup\{(-\infty,a)\cup(b,\infty)\cup\{z\} : a<b\}$ a basis for the topology of $Z$? Have I interpreted your question correctly?

Comment: yes you are correct  just one change in the end of basis set there is a,b in R not a less than b

Comment: Ok, I will try to edit your question so that it is clearer, then!

Answer (score 1):

Concerning 1.:
By considering a constant sequence $(X, X, X, \dots )$, which converges to $X$ and hence has the limit point $X$, you are on the wrong track, since you have to prove that *every* sequence has a limit point and not just the constant ones.

Instead you could proceed as follows:

Consider an arbitrary sequence $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$ in $Z$.

Case 1: 
The sequence is contained in a compact interval $[-n, n], n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then by the Bolzano-Weierstraß Theorem it has a convergent subsequence and hence a limit point.

Case 2: The sequence is not contained in a compact interval. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $a_{i_n} \in (-\infty, -n) \cup (n, \infty) \cup \{z\}$ which is an open neighbourhood of $z$. Hence the subsequence $a_{i_n}$ converges to $z$, i.e. $z$ is a limit point of $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$.